# How to include common components Header and Footer in SPA Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am creating a project spa in vuejs/ I have created common components Header and footer which I want to includes in main App.vue.

I am sharing my Code structure below:

[image]

2. I am sharing my file App.vue:

```html
<template>

 <header></header>

</template>

<script>

import Header from './components/Header.vue'
// import Footer from 'components/Footer.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    // Footer
  }
}
</script>
```

3. In the page of the Vue.js doesn't appear anything any idea how to include header and footer together to display good in spa vuejs.
   Which is wrong in this way?
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

`header` and `footer` are native html elements, you should name your components with uncommon names, for example name them `AppHeader` and `AppFooter` and use them like :

```html
<template>
  <AppHeader />
  <!-- other content-->
  <AppFooter /> 
</template>
<script>
  import {AppHeader} from './components/AppHeader.vue'
  import {AppFooter} from './components/AppFooter.vue'
  export default {
   name:'App',
   components:{ AppHeader, AppFooter}
 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @ Boussadjra Brahim for your answer  really  helped me I was thinked  that I should to include <rotuer-view></rotuer-view> in the App.vue.

Comment: You should include `<router-view></router-view>` inside the App.vue